# How to download BIRT excel report programmatically with specific page range(Downloading BIRT report with specific page range.)

Tags: birt

I have a requirement where I need to programmatically download the BIRT report in excel (xlsx) format and for a specific page range. Like (5-10).

By default it is generating the excel sheet with all the rows. Can anyone please help here.

Note: I am using the org.eclipse.birt.runtime4.4.1.jar.

Regards,
Sandip Mohapatra

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense, because XLSX is not a page-oriented format.
If instead you want to generate an XLSX with only the rows for records e.g. 51-100 then you should use a LIMIT clause in the SQL statement or something like that.